# Drivers Help: Intel AX200 in Dell XPS 15 9570 running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, iwlwifi

My System is dual booted.

I replaced the killer card with intel AX200.

It works on Windows 10 but not on Ubuntu 18.04.

Need help with drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the answer for [Intel wifi Support for AX200 (Cyclone Peak)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149116/intel-wifi-support-for-ax200-cyclone-peak). You can either upgrade to 5.1 kernel which has native support for this device, or install the backport driver (to stay on 4.x kernel) according to the steps in https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release.

If your system has Secure Boot enabled, it will prevent the backport driver from loading automatically (since it is unsigned). To resolve this, you can either sign the modules for the backport driver, or disable Secure Boot altogether. Both options are covered in the answers to [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules).